# How to print out floats in list

Tags: python, nonetype

So I was trying to print out float numbers in a list in reverse but the output keep saying none. Why is that?

```py
nums = [1.4, 1.2054, 2.2, 2.5, 3.66, 3.0, 4.024, 4.00001, 5.5, 5.1]

for i in nums:
    print(nums.reverse())
```

Output:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: You are printing the return value of `nums.reverse()`, and that returns `None`.

Comment: Call reverse() on the list outside the loop.

Comment: have you tried `for l in list(reversed(nums)): print(l)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it just move the nums.reverse() out the loop, then print out the elements.

```
nums = [1.4, 1.2054, 2.2, 2.5, 3.66, 3.0, 4.024, 4.00001, 5.5, 5.1]
nums.reverse()

for i in nums:
    print(i)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 options to reverse a list in Python.

*reverse()* function reverses a list in-place but function itself has no return value.

```
nums = [1.4, 1.2054, 2.2, 2.5, 3.66, 3.0, 4.024, 4.00001, 5.5, 5.1]
nums.reverse()
print(nums)
```

Another option is to create a copy of the list in reverse order.

```
new_list = nums[::-1]
print(new_list)
```

Built-in function *reversed()* creates an iterator of the reversed list and preserves the original list.

```
print(list(reversed(nums)))
```

All 3 options above all output the same reverse list:

```
[5.1, 5.5, 4.00001, 4.024, 3.0, 3.66, 2.5, 2.2, 1.2054, 1.4]
```

Comment: But I need each elements of the list to print out on separate lines

Comment: @Gode if need elements to print on separate lines then use `for n in reversed(nums): print(n)`